# Tortoisehg context menu bug

Tags: windows, mercurial, tortoisehg

[image]

I have [tortoisehg-5.9.2-x64](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/download/index.html) installed on **Windows 8.1 Pro**.
The context menu is showing but when clicking on it nothing happens.

I think it is not linked correctly to the registry.
Any one knows how to fix this or manually link the menu in the registry?

---

> Hint: I have **.NET Framework 4.8** and **Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable**
> [Latest](https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe) version installed.